# Bugzilla - Can I see what I did yesterday?

Tags: bugzilla

I'm running Bugzilla 4.2.5. I would like to save a search to see what I worked on yesterday - so anything that I recorded any time against, or updated the comments for.

I'm hoping that I can then use the output to help with my daily scrum question *"what did you do yesterday?"*

When I go into search -> Advanced Search, I can see a "Search by change history" section which looks exactly like what I'd like to use.

So to test it, I've recorded one hour on a bug assigned to me. I want to be able to find that bug as changed in the last day.

So I go to the "Change history" section, select the field "Hours worked" - (*is there a wildcard I can put in `changed to`?*) In any case I know it has transitioned from zero to 1 hours, so I'll enter "1" into that field.

Next comes the dates, where it says I can enter `YYYY-MM-DD or relative dates`. How do I do a relative date for changed between yesterday and today...? In any case I'll look between 2013-01-01 and 2013-12-31.

It brings back `Zarro Boogs Found`. So what am I doing wrong with the search, I know that I've just changed a bug I'm working on and set one hour of time to it.

I'm hoping someone can help, I've had a good search around for documentation and tried for hours to get this working! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Aha, I've found it,

Advanced search, Custom search, "Hours worked" -> "Changed after" -> "1d"

Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me! Since I sometimes dont fill the "hours worked" field, I added "Status" ->"changed after" -> "1d" and picked "match ANY of .." in the bar on top.